# unable to upload non-image artifacts with cloud build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I have a very simple container (effectively the [Cloud Build quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker) sample code) that generates a file. I'm trying to extend this container to upload said file to a bucket via the documentation on [storing non-image artifacts with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts#articfacts-examples).

My **Dockerfile** builds a trivial container and executes a single script:

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app # the only file present is quickstart.sh
CMD ["./quickstart.sh"]
```

The script (**quickstart.sh**) generates a simple timestamp file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Creating file 'time.txt'"
echo "The time is $(date)" > time.txt

## for debugging:
# pwd
# ls 
# cat time.txt
```

My **cloudbuild.yaml** file is basically copy-pasted from the aforementioned docs, and is configured to upload the file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image', '.' ]
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://my-bucket/'
    paths: ['*.txt']
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

However, the file fails to upload and the build fails as a result. When I run the build command

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

All logs are successful until the end:

```
Artifacts will be uploaded to gs://my-bucket using gsutil cp
*.txt: Uploading path....
CommandException: No URLs matched: *.txt
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
ERROR
ERROR: could not upload *.txt to gs://my-bucket/; err = exit status 1
```

Where `gsutil` is claiming no matching file can be found. However, if I build manually and generate the file, I can use `gsutil cp *.txt gs://my-bucket/` to upload the file with no problem. So it's almost as if the file is wiped before Cloud Build reaches the "upload artifacts" step, but that does not seem like it would make sense. I imagine this is a pretty common use case but I'm not making any progress with the documentation alone. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You are using relative paths in your scripts. Instead, use full paths in output and input file names. The reason is that you are making assumptions (by ignoring them) on the default working directory of both the shell and the programs.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. What you're saying makes sense. However, updating the shell script to write the full path (`/app/time.txt`) and updating the yaml config to read the full path (`/app/*.txt`, `/**/*.txt`, `**/*.txt`) still yields the same error :( Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Check the role of Cloud Build service account. Has it the role to write into your bucket?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the Cloud Build service account role is able to write to the bucket. I can write files to the bucket successfully on build *if they already exist in the local directory*. It's only the file dynamically generated by `quickstart.sh` that is failing to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that with the current steps, you are just building the container and not running it so the time.txt file doesn't get created. Even if you run the container, then the file gets created inside the container so you need to fetch it from inside the container so that gsutil can "see" the file.

I added 2 steps in the **cloudbuild.yaml** file to do this:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image', '.' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'run', '--name', 'containername', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'cp', 'containername:/app/time.txt, './time.txt']
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://mybucket/'
    paths: ['*.txt']
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: This does work, thanks @siamsot. I understand now that **building** does not actually create the file, since **running** is what calls `CMD`, which generates the file. What is less clear, is the requirement to copy the file. After talking with a co-worker, I believe what I'm doing is copying the file from my child `quickstart-image` container into the parent `cloud-builders/docker` container, which is what `gsutil` has access to (as opposed to copying to my local machine). Does that sound right?

Comment: In the way that I understand containers, I would say that there is one container running but in the third step we instruct the Cloud Build worker to go into the container, fetch the txt file and then put it in the working directory. If I'm wrong, someone else can correct me but this is my theory.

Comment: @siamsot i found your post, and thought maybe you have an idea how to get my problem solved? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687647/is-it-possible-within-google-cloud-build-to-build-from-a-dockerfile-and-copy-the