# Is it possible within Google Cloud Build to build from a Dockerfile and copy the result to a storage bucket?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, node-modules, gatsby, google-cloud-build

I have a Gatsbyjs project and trying to get everything to run on Google Cloud Platform using Google Cloud Build.

The steps:

1. New code is pushed into a github repository
2. Google Cloud Build listens for changes on master branch, and triggers a new build
3. Build steps start, install node_modules if needed (first time, updates)
4. Gatsby will build
5. Copy the result from Gatsby build to one of my Storage Buckets.

Why I'm trying to achieve is to cache node_modules as much as possible for new builds.
From what I understand it is possible to add some cache for Docker images so it wont rebuild that everytime.

Is it possible to do it this way once a new build is triggered?:

1. New build is being triggered
2. Use Kaniko with my Dockerfile that contains instructions for npm install and npm run build command
3. Copy the result of the Dockerfile to my storage bucket
4. Complete

Or how would I otherwise be able to cache my node_modules so the build wont take as long time as possible.

In the end it is only static files that I want to store on a bucket as fast as possible.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My current cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  - name: node:12.18.3
    id: 'npm-install'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["install"]
    dir: './gatsby'
  - name: node:12.18.3
    id: 'clean gatsby'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["run", "clean"]
    dir: './gatsby'
  - name: node:12.18.3
    id: 'build-gatsby'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["run", "build"]
    dir: './gatsby'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    id: 'upload-to-bucket'
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", "./public", "gs://[BUCKET-ID]"]
    dir: './gatsby'
```

Comment: Google Cloud Build already stores the container image files (artifacts) in Google Cloud Storage in your account. It would be easier to build locally with Docker and run `docker image save` and then copy the tar archive to Cloud Storage. One item to remember is that a container image is not a single file. It is a set of layers that can be many files depending on the number of steps in your Dockerfile. Google search "docker" and "union file system". https://washraf.gitbooks.io/the-docker-ecosystem/content/Chapter%201/Section%203/union_file_system.html

Comment: But my flow is based more than just code commits, it can be triggered from the CMS to rebuild Gatsby project if new content is added (cms is located on different server). So I need it to be automatically triggered, and then put the files the Docker file generates from npm run build to be put on a specific bucket...?

Comment: Wait, just to be clear: Do you want to copy a container? Or do you want to copy the result of the Cloud Build process? (stored in the /workspace, and you want to push this content into Storage -> that you do at your latest step)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i want to copy the result from my build into a bucket. And try to cache as much as possible during the build step to lower the build time. If that means something else than docker, thats fine.

Comment: Your wish is to speed up the compilation phase right? All the install/clean step are useless for you, you prefer only trigger the `run build` phase when a new file is drop, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to speed up the compilation phase. But I need the install part I guess? Where will it otherwise find node_modules?