# How to upload static content generated inside of a Docker build to Cloud Storage, in a Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, next.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I have a next.js website who generates some of its own static content when being built. Previously it was packaged with this static data inside of the image, but as the size of the static files became large, I want to upload all the static content to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and not have to package them inside the image, which is stored in Google Container Registry.

This is my current dockerfile:

```
# Install dependencies
FROM node:lts-alpine AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Build the base server
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
### ^ At this point the static files are ready and should be uploaded to the bucket.
### I would maybe want to do something like:
RUN gcloud storage cp -r .next/static/ gs://[bucket]/_next/
```

Possible solutions that I can see:

1. Building outside of docker and using Cloud Build's artifact copy action. I would rather not do this because building inside of Docker gives me a lot of certainty and simplicity (I can build the same dockerfile on my local machine and test it)
2. Creating a Service Account specifically for this, transferring the credentials via a secret and then creating another build step which installs the gcloud SDK and copies the files that way. Seems very roundabout, but possible (and will work anywhere…)

Is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687647/is-it-possible-within-google-cloud-build-to-build-from-a-dockerfile-and-copy-the#comment112621197_63687647)